# MySQL query get 0 if no result for day

Tags: php, mysql, flot

I am creating a line graph in flot, I have it all working except for the days which do not have a result I need them to come back with a result 0 + date. Is this possible in mysql? Here is my current query:

```
$chartQuery = "SELECT count(date) as counted_leads, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as time FROM enquiries WHERE visibility != 'deleted' group by date";
```

Or would I need to do it in my php? Here is my code:

```
<?php 
        $last_key = end(array_keys($chartResults));
        foreach ($chartResults as $item => $value)
        {
            $timestamp = round($value['time'] * 1000);

            if ($item == $last_key)
            {
                // last element
                echo '['.$timestamp.', '.htmlentities($value['counted_leads']).']';
            }
            else 
            {
                // not last element
                echo '['.$timestamp.', '.htmlentities($value['counted_leads']).'],';
            }
        }
        unset($value);
        ?>
```

Comment: You can join on a dates/times table, but doing it in PHP might actually just be easier.

Comment: I have updated my post try it.

Comment: If your query returns no rows, what date would you use?

Comment: I was think of pulling through an array of the calender month and looping through if day exists but that seems a bit to much tbh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT time, SUM(counted_leads) AS counted_leads
FROM(
        SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS time, count(1) AS counted_leads
        FROM enquiries
        WHERE visibility != 'deleted'
        GROUP BY time

        UNION ALL

        SELECT a.Date AS time, 0 AS counted_leads
        FROM (
            SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY AS Date
            FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
        ) a
        WHERE a.Date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(date) FROM enquiries) AND (SELECT MAX(date) FROM enquiries)
) a
GROUP BY time;
```

Comment: I have added this in but it doesnt seem to pass back the 0 rows?

Comment: try executing individual query directly on server in UNION ALL.

Comment: Im not familiar with UNION ALL syntax? How would I execute that?

Comment: there are 2 queries inside just execute one by one and see output of individual query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
     ifnull(count(date),0) as counted_leads, 
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as time 
FROM enquiries WHERE visibility != 'deleted' 
group by date
```

Use if null for defult value